# Lighthouse Report - Accessibility contrast issue - Any thoughts on how to resolve?

Tags: colors, accessibility, contrast, lighthouse

I'm trying to improve a Lighthouse accessibility score and know how to address everything it's throwing at me except for one thing.

I have a colour contrast issue whereby I have used a Unicode ★ character for some ratings. It's coloured yellow (#FFD500), but contrast against white background fails AA. I cannot change the colour, but I have provided a text-based alternative (using off-screen positioning) for screen readers. So completely blind people using assistive tech are covered, but I really cannot think how to resolve the low contrast issue for sighted users. I thought to use aria-hidden="true" to stop Lighthouse from assessing it, didn't work.

I can't change colour, I can't change the size, I can't mask it in the report. I guess there's nothing I can do?

Note that I can change the unicode star for an image/svg. This will resolve the issue but for various boring reasons I won't go into, this approach caused other issues (and was what made me opt for unicode characters).

Comment: "I cannot change the colour" - curious why you can't change the color? While many accessibility issues can be resolved purely via code without changing the visual appearance, issues with the design itself can require changing the design in order to make them accessible.

Comment: It's a branding thing. Yellow stars are yellow stars. They'll have that and have an accessibility warning before they change the colour ;)

Comment: So my take is that Lighthouse is doing what Lighthouse is supposed to be doing here. Maybe the issue here isn't how to hack around it (because it's clear that the real fix here involves changing colour - also hack might break in next release), but rather resolving the conflicting requirements of making Lighthouse pass vs keeping the design as-is. *Who* is requiring that Lighthouse pass without errors? They need to get in a room with the design folks, and hammer out which takes precedence.

Answer (score 1):

Stopping Lighthouse from assessing something doesn't make it compliant, and `aria-hidden="true"` hides content from screen readers, but color contrast is an issue for low-vision users, not blind users.

Technically, the color contrast ratio you've got (1.42:1) is too low for any size.

If you absolutely cannot adjust this color, then my recommendation would be to include a text-based alternative nearby, eg:

★ ★ ★ ★
4/5

Comment: Yep, understand all of that. I have a hidden text value for blind users, it's the low vision thing that's the problem here. The simplest solution would be to add a visible value rating (I can push for that), but the stars will still come up as a failure, even if I have a text value alongside it.

Comment: Pretty sure this falls under conforming alternates:

https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/conformance.html#uc-conforming-alt-versions-head

Answer (score 1):

@j-afarian has a nice idea with the text-based rating ("4/5") in addition to the stars, but if the stars are still yellow, it still fails [WCAG 1.4.3](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-contrast.html).  However, 1.4.3 **only** deals with **text** color contrast.  Since you are using unicode, which is essentially text, it's fair game for 1.4.3.

But if you swap out the unicode for an svg or image, as you mentioned, there is no color contrast failure because it's no longer text.  It will still be a problem for low vision users but is not a WCAG failure.  That's kind of gaming the system and defeats the purpose of WCAG, but technically it's not a WCAG failure.

I would love to know the *"various boring reasons"* that caused the problem with svg/img.  We can resolve those too.

If you can't change the (foreground) color of the unicode stars, can you change the background color?

```html
<span style="color:yellow">&#x2605; &#x2605;
  <!-- 4.55 color ratio with gray background -->
  <span style="background-color:#717171">&#x2605; &#x2605;</span>
  <!-- 8.00 color ratio with blue background -->
  <span style="background-color:#0000FF">&#x2605; &#x2605;</span>
  <!-- 4.51 color ratio with red background -->
  <span style="background-color:#E50000">&#x2605; &#x2605;</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Can't set a background colour to contrast it without changing the design/branding. i know what the answer will be ;) As for the boring reasons re SVG - it's a general problem with icon sizing in the dev setup that hasn't been resolved yet whereby SVGs do not size predictably. Honestly, it's very boring. My preference would be to use PNGs (which avoids the issues we have with SVGs in the dev environment), and I may well do that. I was trying to see if there was a fix that I could apply for now with the current approach.

Comment: if you can't change the foreground or background color, i'm not sure what kind of solution you're looking for.  just getting the lighthouse report to ignore the stars does not make it accessible.  svg's are a better choice than png because a low-vision user can bump up the font (ctrl++) and the svg will scale properly whereas a png will become pixelated